# SMTP - How to use a different IP for incoming emails

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

I have a send-only postfix email server where I sent emails via a command line tool
I want to be able to receive emails on a separate provider so that the staff can access the inbox

I have a temporary solution, it is to receive emails on a subdomain: staff.website.com, but I want to use the main domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many SMTP relays as you want and your email server separately working on another provider.
what matters is to have your SMTP relay server IP addresses in your DNS server(SPF Record) as a relay server to make sure your emails are delivered to Inbox.

Just to mention that, when you send emails via command, you don't need to have MX record pointing to your server. By this definition, you can set up your MX record in the DNS server pointing to your provider's IP address plus the correct SPF record and have your other server IP address(Server which you send emails through) as another email-sender defined in the SPF record.

You may also use the following website to generate your SPF record.

https://spfrecord.io/

Comment: so basically you are saying that the ingest relay is the one that needs the MX record bound to it?

Comment: @YaRmgl you are correct YaRmgl. since MX is the address of the receiver email server address. let me show you another production example. [v=spf1  mx ptr mx:alt1.polmx.parsonline.net ip4:213.217.60.3/32 ip4:213.217.60.12/32 ip4:91.99.98.74/32 ip4:213.217.40.74/32 ip4:91.98.98.106/32 ip4:82.99.215.54/32 -all"]

Comment: above is an example of a production SPF record, in which only one IP address is the receiver email server ip address, other IP addresses are the relay servers, to make sure their email are delivered into Inbox.